# Firebase database rules – `data.exists()` always seems to be true, possible bug?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to secure my firebase database to allow the creation of new records, but not allow the deletion of existing records. Ultimately, I plan to utilise Firebase authentication in my app as well, and allow users to update existing records if they are the author, but I am trying to get the simple case working first.

However! No matter what I try in the database rules simulator, despite what the documentation [seems to suggest](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#existing_data_vs_new_data), the value of `data.exists()` seems to always be true. From what I what I can understand from [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#predefined_variables), the variable `data` represents a record in the database as it did before an operation took-place. That is to say, for creates, `data` would not exist, and for updates/deletes, `data` would refer to a real record that exists in the database. *This does not seem to be the case*, to the point where I am actually suspecting a bug in Firebase, as when setting the following rules on my database, **all write operations are disallowed**:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "!data.exists()"
  }
}
```

No matter what values I put into the simulator, be it Location or Data. I have even written a small EmberJS app to verify if the Simulator is telling the truth and it too, is denied permission for all write operations.

I really have no idea where to go from here as I am pretty much out of things to try. I tried deleting all records from my database, which lets the simulator think it can perform write operations, but my test app still gets PERMISSION_DENIED, so I don't know what's causing inconsistencies there.

Is my understanding of the predefined `data` variable correct? If so, why can't I write the rules I want? I have seen [snippets](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/blob/master/docs/guide/security-rules.md) literally trying to achieve my "create only, no-delete"  rule that seem to line up with my understanding.

**Last note**: I am trying this in a totally new Firebase project with JUST the rules above, and only ~a few records of junk data laying around my database.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you have placed the `!data.exists()` at the root location of your database, `data` refers to the entire database.  You will only be able to write to the database when it is completely empty.

You indicate that you run your tests with only *a few records of junk data laying around my database*.  Those records will cause `data.exists()` to be true.

You can achieve your goal by placing the `!data.exists()` rule in your tree at the specific location where you want to require that no data already exists.  This is typically done at a location with a wildcard key, as in the example you linked:

```
{
  "rules": {
    // default rules are false if not specified

    "posts": {
      ".read": true, // everyone can read all posts

      "$postId": {
        // a new post can be created if it does not exist
        // existing posts can only be edited by their original "author"
        ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists() || data.child('author').val() == auth.uid",
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['title', 'author', 'timestamp'])",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. This was the missing piece in my understanding, I clearly had not parsed the documentation properly. I implemented changes like this and now everything is working 100% as expected. I was assuming that `data` was kind of a magically resolved variable which was inferred based on the request you make, and not based on the rules themselves. Thanks!

Comment: I have tried this way in my data base but it always prevent to set new data to the database . This is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073292/simulator-refuse-to-set-new-data-to-firebase-database

Comment: Please help me solving my problem