# Simulator refuse to set new data to firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am adjusting the rules to my firebase database. When I try to set new data to my database I always get denied . This is the rules of my database :

```
 {
  /* Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules. */
  "rules": {

    "challenges":{
      ".write": "auth != null",
      //".write":"auth.uid == \"DFhNb28506Y345CpJ3Ye7DQNn713\" || ((newData.exists() && !data.exists()) || (auth.uid.value == data.child(\"player1Uid\").val() || auth.uid.value == data.child(\"player2Uid\").val()))",
      ".read": "auth != null"
    },

    "comments":{
        ".write": "auth != null",
//      ".write":"auth.uid == \"DFhNb28506Y345CpJ3Ye7DQNn713\" || ((newData.exists() && !data.exists()) || auth.uid.value == data.child(\"writerUid\").val())",
      ".read": "auth != null"
    },

    "lessons":{
       ".write": "auth != null",
      //".write":"auth.uid == \"DFhNb28506Y345CpJ3Ye7DQNn713\" || ((newData.exists() && !data.exists()) || auth.uid.value == data.child(\"writerUid\").val())",
      ".read": "auth != null"
    },

    "posts":{
      ".read": "auth != null",
      //".write": "auth != null"

         "$postId": {
        // a new post can be created if it does not exist
        // existing posts can only be edited by their original "author"
        ".write": "(!data.exists() && newData.exists() && auth != null) || data.child('writerUid').val() == auth.uid || auth.uid == \"DFhNb28506Y345CpJ3Ye7DQNn713\" "
        //".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['title', 'author', 'timestamp'])",
     }
    },

    "questions":{
      ".write": "auth != null",
      //".write":"auth.uid == \"DFhNb28506Y345CpJ3Ye7DQNn713\" || ((newData.exists() && !data.exists()) || auth.uid.value == data.child(\"writerUid\").val())",
      ".read": "auth != null"
    }, 

    "users":{
      ".write": "auth != null",
      //".write":"auth.uid == \"DFhNb28506Y345CpJ3Ye7DQNn713\" || ((newData.exists() && data.child(\"userEmail\").val() != null) || auth.token.email == data.child(\"userEmail\").val())",
      ".read": "auth != null"
    },

  }
}
```

When I try to add new post it always be denied either if I tried to add a new post with the uid that I written it hard coding in the app it also denied. I have spent a very long time trying to set my rules but I can't set it until now and I found that the rules can't be debugged so I hope that someone helps me to solve this problem.

This is my database structure :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to uncomment this line

```
      //    "$postId": {
```

You already have posts in the node "posts", so the `!data.exists` returns false and blocks your new post

Comment: This comment was a mistake during copying the rules please check my update to the rules

Comment: what are you putting in the simulator? I just copied your rules into a project and it lest me write to /posts/postid1

Comment: I writes the location /posts/ because I need to add new post

Comment: I don't need to edit a post I need to create new one

Comment: That's the problem then, you have to write to posts/postid, as your rules are specifying , the node in rules in posts will be created when you push the data, and later you can access it to edit, all that is happening in the postid node, not in posts, where your rules are `".write": "false"`, the default

Comment: But I followed the answer of this questions and the response for it make me feels that it's true

Comment: This is the link of the other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44944969/firebase-database-rules-data-exists-always-seems-to-be-true-possible-bug

Comment: Did you try to push a post from the application? if you cant do that then I suppose you have to put  `".write": "auth != null"` in the posts node, it should't bother you since you are validating every post made in the postid wildcard